# Personalizar un mensaje por consola

Tags: javascript

Tengo un tiempo mirando como grandes sitios web muestran mensajes coloridos por consola a los usuarios para indicarles que no deben estar en esas ares en caso de no ser programadores. Tengo un sitio web en producción y me gustaría hacerle eso mismo a mi sitio para darle ese aire de sitio web importante y más que todo para ganar conocimientos, que al final es lo más importante.

### Lo que quiero lograr es esto

[image: Como quiero mostrar el mensaje por consola]

Quiero mostrar un mensaje de esta forma, con estos colores rojo, para darle a entender al usuario que es una área peligrosa y que no debe estar abriendo esa opción del navegador si este no es programador.

PD: Sé muy bien que este no es un foro en donde pedir como hacer las cosas, es un foro para ayudar a resolver errores, pero tengo algo de tiempo intentando aprender esto y no he aprendido a hacerlo, no se si es porque no es buscado correctamente por Internet o porque no hay información.

Comment: Buen día, algo que puedes incluir en tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida es el código que has intentado (Aunque no funcione), eso hará que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad

Comment: *"Tengo algo de tiempo intentando aprender esto"* -> Literalmente el primer resultado de mi búsqueda de google en 5 segundos me ha dado la respuesta... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console
La búsqueda ha sido "Javascript color console", nada raro. Cuando decís que buscais ... os referís a que intentais encontrar un tutorial en youtube que lo haga por vosotros, o que usais google y stackoverflow? Porque junto con la documentación oficial de tu lenguaje/librería, son las mejores fuentes de conocimiento que existen!

Comment: @Benito-B Sí, justamente de ahí saqué el código de mi respuesta. Pero tal vez el OP no habla inglés y para algo existe este Stackoverflow en español, ¿no crees?

Comment: Si no hablas inglés y te quieres dedicar a la programación te sugiero encarecidamente que aprendas inglés, @Fedex7501. El 90% de la documentación está en inglés, y de cualquier manera... la búsqueda que hice está prácticamente en español, y tomando por ejemplo tu respuesta, solo con entender el código se entiende exactamente la solución, no hay necesidad de saber inglés para encontrar esta solución... basta con saber lo que es `console`, que lo sabe puesto que lo usa. Una de las reglas para preguntar en SO es demostrar que has investigado, no es cosa mía.

Comment: @Benito-B Por qué me lo dices a mí? Yo sí hablo inglés y dije que tal vez el que hizo la pregunta no. Faltó comprensión lectora ahí.

Comment: No, faltó espacio en el comentario @Fedex7501 jajaja. Hablaba en general, no solo a ti. El hecho es que para dedicarse a la programación es necesario el inglés, a eso me refería. Y que la respuesta a lo que afirma haber investigado el autor de la pregunta realmente se entiende sin hablar inglés además... La gente no puede acostumbrarse a preguntar todo en SO para que se lo demos hecho, necesitan investigar y aportar lo investigado en la pregunta, si no a este paso nos convertiremos en otro rincondelvago donde vendrá todo el mundo a copiar y pegar sin importar nada más.

Comment: @Benito-B Hola colega. Justo como yo explique en mi pregunta, donde afirmo que no sé si estoy buscando correctamente por Internet o es que no existe información sobre eso. Si buscas en Internet. ¿Cómo hacer un Dropdow? aparecerá mucha información. Pero cuando buscas por su características, van a aparecer mucho menos resultados, esto debido a que no estas agregando algo concreto en la búsqueda. Espero que hayas entendido un poco mi caso. *Un cordial saludo*

Comment: Tengo un tiempo en la programación, programo en PHP, sé algo de JavaScript, Python y anteriormente estuve aprendiendo Kotlin pero desistí del aprendizaje ya cuando estaba muy avanzado. Sé CSS3, HTML5, SQL, Bootstrap, MaterializeCSS entre otras tecnologías. Y la verdad es que no se ingles. Para programar no es necesario saber ingles, eso desde mi punto de vista. Y si una pagina esta en ingles, pue solo la traduzco y listo. La cuestión es simple, yo no sabia como buscar la información, eso es algo común entre los programadores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le puedes pasar CSS al comando console.log de la siguiente manera:

(Mira el resultado en la consola del navegador)

```js
console.log('%c Stop! ', 'color: red; font-size: 40px');
```

Comment: Buen día, buen aporte, para mejorarlo podrías agregarlo como un fragmento de código usando las teclas "Ctrl" y "M" (Ctrl+M) para que el ejemplo que pongas sea funcional y lo puedan probar de inmediato. Saludos

Comment: @HeytalePazguato justo estaba pensando cómo es que hacen eso. Ya mismo lo pruebo!

Comment: Cuando se inserta una respuesta, en la parte de arriba viene una pequeña barra de herramientas, hay una (La séptima de izquierda a derecha) que sirve para ingresar fracciones de código para JavaScript/HTML/CSS y así crear un ejemplo funcional

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Listo. La única desventaja es que en este caso hay que ver el resultado en la consola del navegador porque en el snippet no le agrega el estilo :(

Comment: Si, es lo que estoy viendo, pero bueno, ya aprendiste a insertar un `snippet` en tus respuestas, éxito!